# use single form to enter multiple profiles

Tags: user-meta, profiles

I want to allow users to add a business profile to their accounts. I have setup a form that posts the business profile information into user meta, and displays that info as part of their main profile.

The challenge: some users will want to create more than one business profile. How can I use a single form to enter multiple business profiles into the database?

I thought about using a counter to increment the user meta key name, but maybe there is a more efficient way?

Comment: Maybe you can create only one meta, `business_profiles` and save data there as array: so when there is only a profile it's an array with one item. After that a `foreach loop` will do the printing stuff. Take the [ACF Reapeter field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/) as example

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for your post. I am using ACF on this site and was thinking about setting up a front end form with a repeater field. Appreciate the confirmation!